# Test browser inactivity

Tags: firefox, selenium, mstest

I'm trying to write a test with Selenium and mstest to test browser inactivity. The site I'm testing will log the user out after 15 minutes of inactivity. I want to be able to test this in a few seconds though. Is there any way to fake browser inactivity through selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to test this in a few seconds though.

That's the crux of the problem isn't it?

For code that I've written where I needed to do this, I would start the test server with the settings needed to shorten the wait. Or if the logic is purely client-side, I'd tell the client-side code that it should shorten the wait. I would do this both at the unit testing level and in system tests. This, obviously, is completely dependent on how my code is structured. There's no general rule. In some cases, I've just set RequireJS to pass a config to my modules to indicate a shorter wait. In other cases, I've executed arbitrary JavaScript code through Selenium to change the timeout settings.

For code that is not mine, I'd try figuring out where this is set and poking it so that it does it faster. If the software that sets the timeout does not cooperate, this may mean replacing some "stock" JavaScript functions like `setTimeout` with your own. How to do this varies depending on which software is used on the web site.

Otherwise, you just have to wait as long as needed for the timeout to occur, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'll see if I can inject a shorter timeout setting. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar testing of this type of functionality.  An app would log a user out after 30 min of inactivity.

How I solved the issue, was to just "sleep".

In Java, I did something like:

```
Thread.sleep(60*30*1000);
// after it's done waiting, the user should be logged out
validateTextPresent("You've been logged out");
```

If this test fails, then that means "You've been logged out" didn't appear, meaning that the user is still logged in.